# Linux: How to get group id from group name? and vice versa?

Tags: linux, bash

I want to retrieve group id of a particular group name. Is there a command in Linux/UNIX systems to do this? Also if I want to do it the other way - get group name from group id, is that also possible?

Comment: An answer to get groudid from group name from another community https://askubuntu.com/a/639998/1577458 which also presents a more explicit version (without short tags) in a comment `getent group root | cut --delimiter ':' --fields 3`)`

Answer (score 71, accepted):

```
getent group 124
# mysql:x:124:

getent group mysql
# mysql:x:124:
```

Answer (score 26):

Given the gid, here is how to get the group name:

```
getent group GID | cut -d: -f1
```

Given the group name, we get the gid:

```
getent group groupname | cut -d: -f3
```

*UPDATE*:

Instead of `cut` a bash builtin can be used:
Example, get the group name for group ID 123.

`` groupid=123 IFS=: read GROUP_NAME REST <<<`getent group $groupid` echo $GROUP_NAME ``

Answer (score 4):

You can use the following command:

```
awk -F\: '{print "Group " $1 " with GID=" $3}' /etc/group | grep "group-name"
```

or

```
cat /etc/group | grep group-name
```

where `group-name` is your group to search.

Answer (score 1):

```
python -c "import grp; print(grp.getgrnam('carmenes').gr_gid)"
```

This uses `getgrnam` from
https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getgrnam.3.html.

Answer (score -5):

I saw [here](https://kb.iu.edu/d/adwf) that you can use the `id` command to get gid or uid from group name or username respectively.

```
id -u username
```

and

```
id -g groupname
```

Comment: man page for `id` says last argument is username, so `id -g foo` will display the name of the main group for user "foo".

Comment: https://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=id+-G+-g+-u